# Verify one of DeMorgan’s Laws for sets

Tags: multisets

Verify one of DeMorgan’s Laws for sets:

$$\bigcap \{S\setminus U:U \in \mathcal U\} = S \setminus \bigcup \{U :U \in \mathcal U\}.$$

Can anyonw show me how to do this? a little confused, thanks

Comment: Begin with: Let $$x \in \bigcap_{ U \in \mathcal{U}}S\backslash U $$ Then show this implies $$x \in S\backslash\bigcup_{ U \in \mathcal{U}}U$$ which establishes that  $$\bigcap_{ U \in \mathcal{U}}S\backslash U \subseteq S\backslash\bigcup_{ U \in \mathcal{U}}U$$ Then do the opposite to complete the proof.

Comment: @graydad : \backslash does not provide proper spacing in things like "$A\setminus B$"; instead you see "$A\backslash B$".  \setminus is standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: That does look better. Thank you for mentioning that

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
& x\in\bigcap \{S\smallsetminus U:U \in \mathcal U\} \\[8pt]
\iff & \forall U \in\mathcal U \quad x\in S\smallsetminus U \\[8pt]
\iff & \forall U\in\mathcal U\quad ( x\in S\ \&\ x\not\in U) \\[8pt]
\iff & x\in S\ \&\ \forall U\in\mathcal U\quad x\not\in U \\[8pt]
\iff & x\in S\ \&\ \lnot\exists U\in \mathcal U\quad x\in U \\[8pt]
\iff & x\in S\ \&\ x\not\in\bigcup \{ U: U\in\mathcal U \} \\[8pt]
\iff & x\in S\smallsetminus \bigcup \{ U: U\in\mathcal U \}.
\end{align}